# Recursive pd.merge() output error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to be able to take a collection of CSV files who share a common index and time `t` with each other and I want to merge them all together using one function called `mergedf()`. It looked to me like it worked except it printed the same set of values 3 times. It seems as though it is printing `filepath[0]` 3 times based off of my `if` statement. In addition, it could also be `intdf` in the `prepdf()` function.

If you could help me spot my error that would be amazing.

**In:**

```
def prepdf(path, mi, ma):
    csv = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=[0,1], skiprows=1, names = ['t','b'])
    df = DataFrame(csv)

    fs = 2  
    T = 1/fs  
    ts = np.arange(mi, ma, T)

    interpdata = {}

    for key in ['b']:
        spl = interpolate.interp1d(df['t'], df[key])
        interpdata[key] = spl(ts)

    interpframe = pd.DataFrame(interpdata, index=ts)
    interpframe.index.name = 'ts'
    interpframe.reset_index(inplace=True)
    interpframe['t'] = interpframe['ts']
    temp = interpframe.loc[interpframe['b'] > 0.5, 't']
    interpframe.loc[interpframe['b'] > 0.5, 't'] = temp
    interpframe['t'] = interpframe['t'].fillna(method='ffill')
    interpframe.set_index('t', inplace=True)
    inttmp = interp_frame
    intdf = interp_frame.head(n=len(inttmp))

    return intdf   

PATHS = ['data1.csv', 'data2.csv', 'data3.csv']
filepath = [file for file in PATHS]

for path in PATHS:
    df = prepdf(path, 650, 1000)
    print(df)

print(len(PATHS))

def mergedf(n):
    if len(PATHS)-1-n == 0:
        return prepdf(filepath[0], 650, 1000)
    else:
        return pd.merge(prepdf(filepath[len(PATHS)-1-n], 650, 1000), mergedf(n+1), left_on='t', right_on='t')

mergedf(0)
```

**Out(mergedf(0)):**

```
    t       b           b_x         b_y
0   650.0   0.105299    0.105299    0.105299
1   650.5   0.193072    0.193072    0.193072
2   651.0   0.115404    0.115404    0.115404
3   651.5   0.047509    0.047509    0.047509
4   652.0   0.119501    0.119501    0.119501
5   652.5   -0.187888   -0.187888   -0.187888
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
695     997.5   0.165262    0.165262    0.165262
696     998.0   -0.131729   -0.131729   -0.131729
697     998.5   0.038266    0.038266    0.038266
698     999.0   0.093568    0.093568    0.093568
699     999.5   0.022013    0.022013    0.022013

700 rows × 4 columns
```

Here is an example of a CSV DataFrame:

```
     t         b
0    650.0  0.105299
1    650.5  0.193072
2    651.0  0.115404
3    651.5  0.047509
4    652.0  0.119501
5    652.5 -0.187888
     ...    ...
```

Comment: Each csv file has the same structure?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes.

Comment: Just wondering... do you mean to "merge" or "concatenate"? Because merge is a horizontal operation...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Well the csvs are shaped m by 2 with a common index that I want them to "merge" on. So b, b_x, and b_y are supposed to be separate csvs made into dataframes

Comment: I see. Have you taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089010/merge-a-list-of-pandas-dataframes)?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes I have although it was throwing me off because they deal with identical values when I don't have identical values in any of the dataframes.

Comment: @JulianRachman, how do you want to merge your data sets if you `"don't have identical values in any of the dataframes"`?

Comment: @MaxU By index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.concat([prepdf(x, 650, 1000) for x in PATHS], axis=1)
```

**UPDATE:**

i guess the problem of showing you the same data set three times was caused by the following lines:

```
intdf = interp_frame.head(n=len(inttmp))

return intdf
```

`interp_frame` - is not defined in the function. Most probably it was defined before in your Python environment (iPython, Jupyter, etc.)

Comment: I am still getting identical b-values in the columns following t. So therefore what you have written doesn't work.

Comment: @JulianRachman, i guess it's because you are using `interp_frame`, which is not defined in your function... Pay attention at the underscore character in the variable name

Comment: Alright we are good! Thank you. I did not think I would need to write out such a long question for such a small syntactical error.